# Mac is overheating, getting slow and unresponsive without any reason

Tags: macos, performance, macbook

About a year ago I noticed my laptop is strongly overheating and CPU raises up to 100% percent without any reason. FYI, no special apps are running. Typical apps to raise such beahavour are:

- Chrome with 1 YouTube video
- Atom text editor
- Dropbox and a few background applications

I thought it's a Chrome and V8 issue, so tried to replace my apps to be as much native as possible: Chrome => Safari, Atom => VIM and removed most of background apps, but no luck. After starting several ordinary apps, strong UI glitches are raised, and the whole system is getting unresponsitive.

CPU temp seems to be OK, process list shows nothing special too. Here's my top and activity montor screens:

[image: htop and Activity Monitor]

Here's CPU temperature, 48*, but both fans are around 6k (6k+ in most of time to be honest).

[image: CPU fan speed]

Have anybody experienced anything similar? I'm far from being a hardware guru, but maybe something with CPU or CPU temperature sensor? Thank you.

**P.S. I'm working with closed lid most of time in closed-clamshell mode, Mac is connected to external display.**

Comment: kernel_task is specifically ramping the CPU usage figure artificially to force the machine to cool. When was the last time the machine was stripped & cleaned? I really suspect poor airflow.

Comment: & if CPU temps are OK, then suspect GPU temps

Comment: @Tetsujin it's a guess. Absolutely calm computer. Started a single YouTube video. In 5 mins: Fan 0 speed: 5927.0 RPM  ▁▂▃▅▆▇, Fan 1 speed: 5497.0 RPM

Comment: @Tetsujin > When was the last time the machine was stripped & cleaned? => Last time at 01.09.2015

Comment: is that 9th Jan or 1st September? Either way, I'd say it's past needing doing again. I do all the machines here 3 or 4 times a year.

Comment: @Tetsujin 1st Sept last year. And can it be cause by working with closed lid somehow?

Comment: Possibly - I don't really use laptops enough to be familiar with their foibles in that respect.